# mongo write lock behavior

Tags: mongodb, locking, pymongo

I have a question on mongo locks. Basically I have to perform some write operation on the table(insert/ delete/ update). When I read this link [Locking in Mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/). It says "Locks are “writer greedy,” and when a write lock exists, a single write operation holds the lock exclusively, and no other read or write operations may share the lock.

My question is -- The lock is memory block based or we have a single lock on entire db. What I was thinking is concurrently run 2 scripts scanning 2 memory blocks of mongodb (planning to scan 2 million documents in one query) and perform write operation side by side thereby increasing the performance and saving time.

I searched on net about this but didnt find anything satisfactory.

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 5):

The write lock has nothing to do with memory, MongoDB is not an in-memory database, the OS merely caches the working set of the `mongod` process to RAM. MongoDB has no memory hooks in its program.

The write lock is also on database level as such your plan is not feasible.

Comment: As an addendum to Sammaye's point, if your application is going to be very write-heavy (e.g., storing logs), it might be useful just to have multiple databases. Then you could have a scripts running concurrently on each database.

Comment: @llovett good point though I would like to stress only in the highest of write cases have I seen multiple databases help, it takes a serious amount of writes for the lock hinder MongoDB due to its nature.